# O que significa #document?

Tags: html, parse

Boa noite pessoal, estou analisando um código fonte para fazer um parse e me deparei com um trecho do código em que aparece um **#document** porém nunca vi isso na vida, dei um Google aqui mas não encontrei nada referente. Alguém sabe o que é isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este `#document` é um **"elemento virtual"**, ou seja, é uma forma específica do seu browser te indicar que é parte de um `DOM` **(incorporado) diferente**. **Não é possível utilizá-lo ou consultá-lo**, pois o **"elemento virtual"** **não existe como parte do** `DOM` **do código.**

Em resumo geral o `#document` **não significa realmente nada!**

Comment: Quando você diz que eu não posso consultá-lo, significa que eu não consigo fazer o parse no html que está dentro desse elemento virtual? Estou tentando fazer a extração com utilização do Jsoup, poderia me dar alguma dica?

Comment: @Lucas exatamente, você não consegue consultá-lo e utilizá-lo de quaisquer forma, ele foi inserido lá de alguma forma, talvez por um iframe, mas não posso afirmar porque não tenho a estrutura do site real.

Comment: Posso inserir a estrutura para ver se consegue me passar alguma dica a mais? Aparentemente usaram iframe mesmo.

Comment: Poder você pode, mas o funcionamento no domínio è diferente do código copiado e colado aqui, então não adianta nada. Talvez se eu puder acessar este sim, rodando no domínio original da para dizer se tem alguma solução ou não.

Comment: O link para o a página seria este [AQUI](http://nfe.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfeweb/sites/nfce/d/danfeNFCe?p=52190503044201000502650060000900821061414640|2|1|2|EDBAD825876DC41E9CB6C13AC61E0636309C8BC4). A estrutura consta de um HTML -> IFRAME -> #document -> HTML.

Comment: Consegui acessar a parte que eu precisava aqui via Jsoup, porém, ela está dentro de um javascript o que vai dificultar o trabalho na hora de executar as seleções. Vou tentando aqui. Abraços e obrigado pela ajuda.